How to enumerate each hours of a day
I want to get each hours of a day, local time. For places without daylight saving time it is easy, but when there DST start or ends, current days have 23 or 25 hours!
I wrote this code to properly get it, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way with chrono to write the function PrintHours()
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr const char* zoneName = "Europe/Berlin";

void PrintHours(std::chrono::local_days date)
{
    zoned_time utcTime{"UTC", zoned_time{zoneName, date}};
    auto localTime = zoned_time{zoneName, utcTime};

    auto dp = std::chrono::floor<days>(localTime.get_local_time());
    // keep looping until day change!
    for (auto startingDay = year_month_day{dp}.day(); startingDay == year_month_day{dp}.day(); dp = std::chrono::floor<days>(localTime.get_local_time()))
    {
        std::cout << zoneName << localTime<< " UTC: " <<  utcTime << std::endl;

        // bump time to next hour
        utcTime = zoned_time("UTC", utcTime.get_local_time() + hours(1));
        localTime= zoned_time{zoneName, utcTime};
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    year_month_day ymd{year(2023), month(10), day(29)};
    PrintHours(local_days(ymd));
    return 1;
}


The following:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr const char* zoneName = "Europe/Berlin";

void PrintHours(year_month_day day) {
    // get the year-month-day 00:00:00 in the specific timezone.
    for (auto it = zoned_time(zoneName, local_days(day));
         // Get the day in the iterator and compare with starting day.
         year_month_day(floor<days>(it.get_local_time())).day() == day.day();
         // Increment the day in one hour and come back to the timezone.
         it = it.get_sys_time() + hours(1)) {
        std::cout << it << '\n';
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PrintHours(year_month_day{year(2023), month(10), day(29)});
    return 1;
}

Outputs:
2023-10-29 00:00:00 CEST
2023-10-29 01:00:00 CEST
2023-10-29 02:00:00 CEST
2023-10-29 02:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 03:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 04:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 05:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 06:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 07:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 08:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 09:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 10:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 11:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 12:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 13:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 14:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 15:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 16:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 17:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 18:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 19:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 20:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 21:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 22:00:00 CET
2023-10-29 23:00:00 CET


This is very good.  The version I came up with before I looked at yours has two minor improvements:  1). The increment can be done by simply: it = it.get_sys_time() + 1h.  That is, you can assign a sys_time directly back into a zoned_time without the need to construct a temporary zoned_time.  2) You can easily print out the equivalent UTC time in the body with format("{:%F %T %Z}", it.get_sys_time()).  I consider these two tweaks minor enough that they don't warrant an additional answer.

One more tweak that I neglected to mention above:  The test in the for-loop would be more efficient as floor<days>(it.get_local_time()) == date where date is defined as in the question.  This avoids a conversion from serial to fields for each iteration, and serves the same purpose.

Using modern c++ standard
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <date/date.h>
#include <ranges>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::ranges;

namespace {
    constexpr const char* zoneName = "Europe/Berlin";

    void PrintHours(const chrono::local_days& date) {
        auto zone = date::locate_zone(zoneName);
        date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds> localTime(zone, date);

        cout << "Hours of the day in " << zoneName << ":\n";
        for (int hour : views::iota(0, 24)) {
            auto specificHour = localTime + hours(hour);
            cout << date::format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", specificHour) << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    year_month_day ymd{year{2023}, month{10}, day{29}}; // Example date: October 29, 2023
    PrintHours(local_days{ymd});
    return 0;
}


Isn't this missing headers (<iostream> and <date/tz.h>)? Also, none of the Date versions I have access to has a zoned_time that can be constructed from the types you use. using both std::chrono and data also causes ambiguity. It's best not to mix them so it's clear from where you actually intend to pick a type.

The reason this line: auto specificHour = localTime + hours(hour) doesn't compile is because it is inherently ambiguous.  As I read it, I really don't know exactly what is intended.  Do you want to add an hour to the underlying local time or to the underlying UTC time?

views::iota(0, 24) What about days with 25 hours? You can't hardcode that.

there are days with 23 hours, 24 and 25, this is what I need to enumerate for a UI.
so I cannot use iota and assume a fixed number of hours.
Also I wanted to use the chrono library, not the Hinnant one.
